# Open new Outlook email with thousands of recepients

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I recently tried to open a new outlook email from my C# windows forms application.

The following code works fine for about 200 recipient email adresses:

```
Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem) outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMailItem.GetInspector;

Outlook.Recipients oRecipients = (Outlook.Recipients)oMailItem.Recipients;
foreach (String email in recipients)
{
    Outlook.Recipient oRecipient = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecipients.Add(email);
    oRecipient.Resolve();
}

oMailItem.Display(true);
```

It opens a new outlook mail window, adds the recipients to the respective field and lets me write the rest of the email.

**The problem:** The email window takes minutes to come up when i try to add more than 200 recipients. The more recipients, the longer it takes to come up. If there are roughly more than 500 recipients, the mail window does not come up at all. My company has use cases where i need to add up to 10.000 recipients though, e.g. for special announcements.

I tried opening this email window in a background thread to see if it helps, but there was no difference.

Is there any way to make this work for such a huge amount of recipients?
Or is Outlook just not designed to open an email window with thousands of recipients?

Comment: *Don't* send emails with thousands of recipients unless you are a spammer and want to **intentionally** leak your customer's emails. And have your company pay 10% of its annual revenue as a GDPR fine. It's not Outlook's fault.

Comment: Sorry, level 1 fines are 2% or €10Μ, level 2 4% or €20M

Comment: In any case did you try to open this email with **Outlook**? Your code can't affect how **Outlook** opens the email. It can't prevent email servers from dropping it either, as 10K recepients is a clear sign of spamming. In fact, such emails will get your company blacklisted *fast*

Comment: *"My company has use cases where i need to add up to 10.000 recipients though, e.g. for special announcements."* You better get a MailChimp account or something like that. If a company sends me an email with 10.000 recipients I'd instantly lose **all** trust in their competence.

Comment: If you want to send a lot of emails, *send a lot of emails*. Many servers like Exchange have distribution lists anyway, that send to all recipients whatever you post to the list. Or subscribe to a mass mailing service, or use the cloud email services provided by Amazon, Azure. The **email servers** will send one email to each of the 500 recipients anyway. You aren't making *anything* easier by stuffing everyone in the `To` field.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer if a company sends *you* an email, with 10K recipients they get an instant 10M fine. You wouldn't have to lose trust, they would probably cease to exist

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos At least in the EU, no idea how something like this would be handled elsewhere in the world.

Comment: @user2677466 You should [read this](https://blog.mailrelay.com/en/2017/12/07/be-ready-for-new-email-marketing-anti-spam-and-gdpr-laws-in-your-country)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer you are in the EU, therefore the company has to follow the rules no matter where it's based. And that goes for intermediaries too. That's why GDPR affects almost everyone. What partner would continue working with a known GDPR violator and risk getting fined as well?

Comment: It seems i didn't make clear who the recipients are. Sorry for that. The email to be sent is going to internal recipients only. Its the companys own employees that should recieve that email. I think that should not be spam or subject to any fine, right?

Comment: It's still bad practice. Use an email distributor / groups or add everybody as BCC instead of TO.

Answer (score 1):

As the many comments alluded to, you *don't* send emails with 10,000 recipients in one shot. Additionally, Outlook is completely the wrong tool for the job. You need to be going directly to a service for this. If you don't have Exchange available (which has its own API), subscribe to a bulk sending service. They're very cheap, 10K is considered low-volume and would only cost you a few dollars per month. They typically handle millions per customer per month.

We use Mailgun for our subscriber base, and there are others. Microsoft pushes SendGrid pretty heavily to Azure subscribers. Mailgun's documentation does a great job of explaining how to avoid getting yourself flagged as a spammer: [Email Best Practices](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/best_practices.html).

Even their own bulk mailing service "only" supports batches of 1000 at a time.

[Sending Email](https://www.mailgun.com/sending-email)

> With a single API call, you can send up to 1000 fully personalized emails.